# java code for PDF to XML conversion

Tags: java, xml, pdf

i tried with itext and could not get xml format
i want to convert pdf to xml
i just want text(location,size) which is available in **XML** format and so any one help ne in   conversion of **PDF** to **XML** using java

Answer (score 4):

There is a library [pdf2htmlEX](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/) which can convert the pdf to html without losing text or format.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use in my own applications. I don't remember where I got it from, but it sure works like a charm.

```
  public class ConvertPDFToXML {
            static StreamResult streamResult;
            static TransformerHandler handler;
            static AttributesImpl atts;

            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

                    try {
                            Document document = new Document();
                            document.open();
                            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\hello.pdf");
                            PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(1);
                            PRIndirectReference objectReference = (PRIndirectReference) page
                                            .get(PdfName.CONTENTS);
                            PRStream stream = (PRStream) PdfReader
                                            .getPdfObject(objectReference);
                            byte[] streamBytes = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
                            PRTokeniser tokenizer = new PRTokeniser(streamBytes);

                            StringBuffer strbufe = new StringBuffer();
                            while (tokenizer.nextToken()) {
                                    if (tokenizer.getTokenType() == PRTokeniser.TK_STRING) {
                                            strbufe.append(tokenizer.getStringValue());
                                    }
                            }
                            String test = strbufe.toString();
                            streamResult = new StreamResult("data.xml");
                            initXML();
                            process(test);
                            closeXML();
                            document.add(new Paragraph(".."));
                            document.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
            }

            public static void initXML() throws ParserConfigurationException,
                            TransformerConfigurationException, SAXException {
                    SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory
                                    .newInstance();

                    handler = tf.newTransformerHandler();
                    Transformer serializer = handler.getTransformer();
                    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
                    serializer.setOutputProperty(
                                    "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
                    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                    handler.setResult(streamResult);
                    handler.startDocument();
                    atts = new AttributesImpl();
                    handler.startElement("", "", "data", atts);
            }

            public static void process(String s) throws SAXException {
                    String[] elements = s.split("\\|");
                    atts.clear();
                    handler.startElement("", "", "Message", atts);
                    handler.characters(elements[0].toCharArray(), 0, elements[0].length());
                    handler.endElement("", "", "Message");
            }

            public static void closeXML() throws SAXException {
                    handler.endElement("", "", "data");
                    handler.endDocument();
            }
    }
```

Comment: but i'm not able to get data from the above code (by the way this code from roseindia)

Comment: Oh oh! yeah! It's from roseindia. I just couldn't remember where I got it from. Anyway, you are not able to get data? I don't understand.

Comment: i just want to read pdf file entire text in the form of co-ordinates and the text, but the text could not be retrieved using above code can  u help me

Comment: Could not be retrieved ? you are getting errors ?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray cannot be     cast to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRIndirectReference  
 at ConvertPDFToXML.main(ConvertPDFToXML.java:24)  this is the error i got